# My vim and gvim are far too slow

Tags: perl, vim

I'm mainly using terminal vim and/or gvim 7.2 to work on my Perl project with following plugins:

- CSApprox, SnipMate, PerlOmni, TaskList, TagList, NerdTree, ACP (Auto Complete Popup)

The problem is editing a big files takes a few seconds for vim/gvim to autocomplete when I do C-N or C-X-O.

I've tried to do **"set complete-=i"** to remove the include files from the search list, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem and found a solution?

thanks!

Comment: Whenever I run vim on very large files I turn off reading of my .vimrc file.  You may want to run a different .vimrc file with some of those plugins turned off when in `large file mode` my creating a new .vimrc file called whatever and then using the `-u` option to load that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue a few months ago and it turned out to be to do with how folds are calculated. Setting foldmethod to manual only whilst in insert mode solved the issue. This doesn't change the current folds and has the added bonus that folds after your insertion point aren't opened.

```
"Sourced from vim tip: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text
autocmd InsertEnter * if !exists('w:last_fdm') | let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * if exists('w:last_fdm') | let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm | unlet w:last_fdm | endif
```

Hopefully this helps as this issue was driving me crazy!

Comment: Greg, you're a ripper. It solves the issue straight away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I also find the same problem when I am using NeoComplCache. When I edit a large js file, it takes a long time when I press key to type a word, actually, it take a long time that some plugin is trying to search the whole buffer and give you some suggestion. Vim script itself is not so much efficient for process large text.

I suggest to remove ( or close if possible ) some of the auto-complete plugin and try again. Furthermore, if possible, select the minimum set of the vim extension that you think it is really useful for you and remove others.